# SQLite high scores, CursorIndexOutOfBounds - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

I commented in the code below in both spots the IOOF exception is happening.  I know for sure through testing that the db creates correctly and I am able to insert into it.  I am trying to integrate everything together after testing and its not working now.  LogCat is below also.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
private static final String RANK = "_id"; 
private static final String SCORE = "score"; 
private static final String PERCENTAGE = "percentage";
private static final String SUM = "sum";

public long getScore(int rank) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + RANK + " = " + rank, null);
      c.moveToFirst();
    long i = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("SCORE") + 1);
    c.close();
    return i;
}

public int getPercentage(int rank) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + PERCENTAGE + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + RANK + " = " + rank, null);
      c.moveToFirst();
    int i = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTAGE") + 1);  //Line 56
    c.close();
    return i;
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ("
        + RANK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + SCORE + " LONG,"
        + PERCENTAGE + " INTEGER,"
        + SUM + " INTEGER"
        + ");");
```

Highscores.java

```
onCreate(...) {

    r1p.setText("Row1 P: " + dh.getPercentage(1));  //Row 90
    r1s.setText("Row1 S: " + dh.getScore(1));

    r2p.setText("Row2 P: " + dh.getPercentage(2));
    r2s.setText("Row2 S: " + dh.getScore(2));

    r3p.setText("Row3 P: " + dh.getPercentage(3));
    r3s.setText("Row3 S: " + dh.getScore(3));

    //etc...
```

LogCat output

```
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Highscores}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.getPercentage(DatabaseHelper.java:58)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at com.example.test.Highscores.onCreate(Highscores.java:90)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-04 00:30:28.462: E/AndroidRuntime(5440):     ... 11 more
```

EDIT:  I integrated what was suggested and now the error is on the same line but I think slightly different.  I updated my LogCat output above.

Comment: As a note, you are using `getColumnIndex()` incorrectly. you should use `c.getColumnIndex(SCORE)`.

Comment: Instead of putting double quotes around the arguement?

Comment: Correct and don't add 1 to the result anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `moveToFirst()` before doing a get on `Cursor` .

```
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + RANK + " = " + rank, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    //It is always better to do hasNext() check here. Just to make sure rows are available otherwise it may throw exception.
    long i = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("SCORE") + 1);
```

See this [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) on how to use Cursor.

Comment: Hey @Nambar, I updated my code and am still getting the same error on the same line.  I think the error message may be slightly different.  The updated the LogCat and code in my opening post.

Comment: @user1866707: As I commented in my answer, if you don't do hasNext() and NO rows available you will see the exception you are seeing right now. Read the tutorial linked in my answer to avoid it. Add that do/while condition.

Comment: Working!  I've accepted this answer now.  I've added that do/while condition.  But now ````c.moveToFirst()```` always returns false.  I know my ````insert()```` does insert into the db.  I am thinking my RANK/AUTOINCREMENT might now be working correctly.

Comment: @user1866707: I would try hardcoding query first and make sure rows are being returned before going too deep.